# How to use your Scala classes in android

Tags: android, scala, gradle

We have a bunch of business objects modeled as Scala case classes. I would dearly love to use these classes in out Android apps to avoid duplication.

When I publish the artifact that contains our classes to our repository and import into android with Gradle I get the following exception:

```
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

I believe that this is caused because the project now exceeds the 65k method limit for dex. Just to be clear the project only has our case classes as a dependency. The according to the.pom, the transitive dependencies of our case classes look like this:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatestplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>play_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am excluding scalatest within gradle so my gradle dependencies look like this:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3
 \--- ourcompany:ourscalacaseclasses_2.11:1.2.22
      +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1
      \--- joda-time:joda-time:2.7
```

So it seems to me that the problem is that gradle is pulling all of scala lang in order to use these classes and this is causing the dex to be huge.

Is there a way to use Scala classes in android without:

A: Going the multi-dex route

B: Using scaloid or otherwise rewriting all of our android code in Scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only pill from "65k limit" i know is Proguard. Create proguard file for Android and Scala [like that one](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/blob/master/resources/android-proguard.config), and feed your favorite IDE with it.

But if you plan to develop for Android in Scala, i'd suggest IntelliJ + Sbt + [Android-sdk-plugin](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

There are some pretty cool open sourced libraries for doing this. Please have a look on **Scaloid**

https://github.com/pocorall/scaloid

Scaloid is a library that simplifies your Android code. It makes your code easy to understand and maintain by leveraging Scala language.

For example, the code block shown below:

```
val button = new Button(context)
button.setText("Greet")
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  def onClick(v: View) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Hello!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }
})
layout.addView(button)
```

is reduced to:

```
SButton("Greet", toast("Hello!"))
```

Comment: I am aware of Scaloid. I think it's great. But what I need here is a way to use some of our Scala classes in our android apps, without re-writing those apps in Scala and ideally without having to adopt a different build tool (sbt vs gradle)

Comment: Taking a look at it it seems that hitting the 65k limit is inevitable when developing Scala apps in Android. I should probably just accept that I will have to use proguard or multidex.